# How to add up the number representations of the objects of the hashes in an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An array of hashes like

```
  [{color: "red", size: "large"},{color: "blue", size: "small"},{color: purple, size: "medium"},{color: "pink", size: "small"}]
```

Also another hash:

```
  {small: 1, medium: 2, large: 3, x_large: 4}
```

How would someone replace all the sizes by their respective numbers and sum up those numbers?

The problem could be solved manually by replacing the numbers with the sizes like so:

```
 [{color: "red", size: 3},{color: "blue", size: 1},{color: purple, size: 2},{color: "pink", size: 1}]
```

Then adding them up the number representation of the sizes would output: 7

Comment: Please give us your expected output. The two inputs you've provided seem to be completely unrelated, it's impossible to tell how you expect to combine them.

Comment: I edited the question to show how I would answer the problem manually.  Is there any other information you would like?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your first array, replace `:size` with the corrospoding size from the second array:

```
arr = [{color: "red", size: "large"},{color: "blue", size: "small"},{color: "purple", size: "medium"},{color: "pink", size: "small"}]

sizes =   {small: 1, medium: 2, large: 3, x_large: 4}


arr.each do |x|
  x[:size] = sizes[x[:size].to_sym]
end
```

Comment: I'm sure they value results when writing real code, and I'm equally sure that a **test** wasn't given with the intent of having you copy-paste it into the Internet and regurgitate the top solution as your own. As for it being "your idea" to use map/inject to make it "more rubyesque", you clearly don't know rubyesque code from non rubyesque code.