# How to use inject or map to iterate through an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

There is an array of hashes like:

```
arr = [
  {color: "red", size: "large"},
  {color: "blue", size: "small"},
  {color: "purple", size: "medium"},
  {color: "pink", size: "small"}
]
```

and a hash:

```
sizes = {small: 1, medium: 2, large: 3, x_large: 4}
```

I would like to know how to replace all the sizes by their respective numbers and sum those numbers. I know how to do this using `each` as follows:

```
arr.each do |x|
  x[:size] = sizes[x[:size].to_sym]
end
```

How would someone do this using `inject` or `map`?

Comment: In what sense are the numbers summed?

Comment: @Graeme.  I see what happened.  I only skimmed the [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258994/how-to-add-up-the-number-representations-of-the-objects-of-the-hashes-in-an-arra), then read meagar's answer, which did not address the summing of the values.  Originally, the question did not ask for the the values to be summed.  That was added after meagar answered.  As there were no other answers (and meagar chose not to amend his answer [hmmm]), the asker did not get an answer to the summing part, hence the new question.

Comment: @sawa you replace the sizes with their respective numbers and then you add them up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [
  {color: "red", size: "large"},
  {color: "blue", size: "small"},
  {color: "purple", size: "medium"},
  {color: "pink", size: "small"}
]

sizes =   {small: 1, medium: 2, large: 3, x_large: 4}

arr.map { |x| x[:size] = sizes[x[:size].to_sym] }.inject(:+)
# => 7
arr
# => [{:color=>"red", :size=>3}, {:color=>"blue", :size=>1}, 
# =>  {:color=>"purple", :size=>2}, {:color=>"pink", :size=>1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do as :

```
ar = [
       {color: "red", size: "large"}, {color: "blue", size: "small"},
       {color: 'purple', size: "medium"},{color: "pink", size: "small"}
     ]
hash = {small: 1, medium: 2, large: 3, x_large: 4}
ar.inject(0) { |sum,elem_hash| sum + hash[elem_hash[:size].to_sym] }
# => 7
```